# typing in textarea triggers render in livewire

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I have a textarea and when I type in it, render function works. What is the problem?

```php
<label class="tf-form-label" for="form.reason">
    {{ __('Reason') }}
</label>
<textarea wire:model.debounce.250ms="form.reason" rows="5" name="form.reason" id="form.reason" class="tf-input" ></textarea>
<x-jet-input-error for="form.reason" class="mt-2" />
```

Comment: this is the default livewire behavior that re-render the view after every network request

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is the default behaviour when you bind an element to a Livewire. Debounce does not prevent this, just provides control over when Livewire triggers a network request to update itself.

If you don't want to update on every character input, you either want to use the [`lazy`](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/properties#lazy-updating) which sends a network request when it detects the native `change` event, or [`defer`](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/properties#deferred-updating) which batches updates and sends them when you explicitly tell the form to submit.